# Given the contour plot of $C(x, y) = > e^{-(x^2+2y^2)/10^4}$ find the path from (100, 100) to (0, 0) where f increases most rapidly..?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a problem from my workbook for my multivariate calculus course for uni, and I am not sure how best to solve it.
I am given the equation $C(x, y) = e^{-(x^2+2y^2)/10^4}$, and need to find the path from (100, 100) to (0, 0) on the contour plot of the function along which f increases most rapidly, and then guess the equation of this path.

I am not sure how I am supposed to go about this.
If someone wouldnt mind lending a hand, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks
Tim

EDIT:
Contour plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The direction in which $f$ increases the fastest is the gradient of $f$. The norm of the gradient of $f$ is the rate of fastest increase.

To guess the equation, I suppose you should sketch the contour using some tool, and look at the shape of it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, its much appreciated, but I am still unsure of how I would find the equation. I have included the contour plot in my original post, but I dont see how I would find the required equation from that... Thanks again, Corey

Comment: @Fishingfon: If you draw the path correctly, (perpendicular to the contour lines) you should get kind of a parabola.